# Meaning of my ($H,$M,$S) = $date =~ m{^([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})} in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am new to perl. Can anyone explain the meaning of the following line of code:

```
my ($H,$M,$S) = $date =~ m{^([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})}
```

I assume that after the execution of this line `$H`, `$M` and `$S` will have the values extracted from `$date`. Can anyone explain to get a better understanding?

Comment: `()` denotes capture groups in regex. You capture, generate a list, and then assign to the LHS 'list' (of scalar variables)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It tries to match the contents of the `$date` variable, with a regex:

```
^([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})
```

The regex basically means: from the start of the string, there should be two digits and colons repeated three times. Each of these three two digit numbers are enclosed in a group.

Finally, the matches of the three groups are assigned to local variables `$H`, `$M` and `$S`.

---

For example if

```
$date = "10:37:21 2016.01.02";
```

then

```
$H = "10";
$M = "37";
$S = "21";
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear cut answer. 

Just to confirm, the input string should be in following format to match the regex: 05:15:25
Is that correct?

Comment: @siju, yes, it should start with that format, it can have something after that though.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone explain to get a better understanding?

You need to start to be aware of two things:

1. list context
2. scalar context

The match operator, `m//`, will provide different results depending on what's on the left hand side of your `=` sign.  Check this out:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;

my $result =  "abc" =~ m/a(.)(.)/;
say $result;   #=> 1

my @results = "abc" =~ m/a(.)(.)/;
for my $result (@results) {
    say $result;
};

--output:--
b
c
```

A `$variable` can only store one thing, so when there is a $variable on the left hand side of the `=` sign, the $variable looks over to the match operator, `m//`, on the right hand side of the `=` sign and calls out, "Hey, I can only store one thing over here, just give me one thing, please!"  The match operator responds by returning 1, for true, if there was a match; or 0, for false, if there wasn't a match.

On the other hand, when an `@variable` is on the left hand side of the `=` sign, the array looks over to the `m//` operator and calls out,  "Hey, I can store a bunch of things over here, so give me a bunch of stuff, please!"  The match operator responds by returning what matched the capture groups in the regex if there was a match; if there wasn't a match, the match operator returns `()`.

In the first case, the `$variable` is said to provide `scalar context` for the match operator.  In the second case, the `@variable` is said to provide `list context` for the match operator.  Don't let those terms scare you.  You know what they mean now.

Next, when you write this:

```
my ($H,$M,$S) =
```

You are creating several variables on the left hand side of the `=` sign.  In unison, they call out to the match operator on the other side of the `=` sign, "Hey, there are many of us over here, give us the bunch of stuff, please!  That particular `my` syntax provides a `list context` for the match operator which is on the right hand side of the `=` sign:

```
my ($group1, $group2) = "abc" =~ m/a(.)(.)/;
say $group1;  #=> b
say $group2;  #=> c
```

Note that if the delimiters you use for the match operator are `m/.../`, then you don't have to write the leading `m`, so typically you will see the example above written as:

```
my ($group1, $group2) = "abc" =~ /a(.)(.)/;
```

When you use braces like you did: `m{...}{...}`, then you have to write the leading `m`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simpler regex, which is easier to understand, to do what you want:

```
 \d{2}  #\d means a digit, {2} means twice,
        #so this matches two consecutive digits
```

Here's how you can use that regex:

```
#Just blindly use all three of these in every program:
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;    

my $date = "10:37:21 2016.01.02";

my ($H,$M,$S) = $date =~ /\d{2}/g;  #g => global, Find all matches in the string

say $H;  #say() is the same as print() with a newline at the end
say $M;
say $S;

--output:--
10
37
21
```

The regex starts at the beginning of the string and looks for two consecutive digits and finds 10, so that is a match; then the regex jumps over the `:` and finds 37, so that is a match; then the regex jumps over the `:` and finds 21, so that is a match; etc., etc.

When you assign all the matches to three variables, the first three matches are assigned to the three variables, and the rest of the matches are discarded.